# La función se declara pero no se usa

Tags: windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, sql

Escribo este código, pero al momento de ejecutar, me indica error, dice que esta función se declara pero no se usa
¿A que se debe este error?

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "samara" && textBox2.Text == "12345")
    {
        Form2 llamar = new Form2();
        llamar.Show();
    }
    if (textBox1.Text == "carrico" && textBox2.Text == "67890")
    {
        Form2 llamar = new Form2();
        llamar.Show();
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("usuario incorrecto");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

la razon por la que esta declarada pero no se usa es porque no esta asignada a ningun evento. Para asignar un evento puedes hacerlo por ejemplo:

```
Button b = new Button();
// Asignandole al evento Click de un boton
b.Click = Button1_Click;
```

O a un boton previamente creado desde el diseñador. Esto se haces seleccionando el boton en la vista diseño y en la ventana de propiedades seleccionar la pestaña eventos y en evento Click desplegar la lista y elegir "Button1_Click"

Este ocurre generalmente cuando creas un evento desde el diseñador y lo borras accidental o intencionalmente, y queda la función generada